# Positive divisors of n = $2^{14} \cdot 3^9 \cdot 5^8 \cdot 7^{10} \cdot 11^3 \cdot 13^5 \cdot 37^{10}$

Tags: combinatorics

How do I find positive divisors of n that are **perfect cubes that are multiples of 2^10 * 3^9 * 5^2 * 7^5 * 11^2 * 13^2 * 37^2**

The answer is (1)(1)(2)(2)(1)(1)(3) = 12

I don't understand though because I would have done something like:

2: [(14-10)/3]+1 = 2 (taking the floor)

3: [(9-9)/3]+1 = 1

5: [(8-2)/3]+1 = 3

7: [(10-5)/3]+1 = 2

11: [(3-2)/3]+1 = 1

13: [(5-2)/3]+1 = 2

37: [(10-2)/3]+1 =3

2*1*3*2*1*2*3

Comment: There is exactly one multiple of three between $10$ and $14$ (*inclusive*), namely $12$, which is why there is exactly one possible exponent for $2$ in the types of numbers we desire to count.  Your mistaken approach seems to think there are two for some reason.  While it is possible for some ranges of five consecutive integers to contain two multiples of $3$ (*for example 3,4,5,6,7*) it is also possible for five consecutive integers to only contain one multiple of three (*for example 10,11,12,13,14*), so there is more to it than simply the length of the interval in question.

Comment: @JMoravitz Interesting, wonder if given a random interval like $[10, 14]$, is it possible to find a formula for the exact number of multiples of $3$.

Comment: @rsadhvika of course, and it will depend on the lower bound's remainder when divided by 3

Comment: @JMoravitz for the interval $[a, b]$, something like $$\left\lceil \dfrac{b-a+1}{3}\right\rceil + a \pmod{3}$$
? I'm not sure if it works, still testing..

Comment: Looks I have it. Number of divisors of $n$ over the interval $[a,b]$ is $$\left\lfloor \dfrac{b-a+  a \pmod{n}}{n}\right\rfloor $$

does that look okay to you @JMoravitz

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm pretty sure it can be made simpler, but not sure how.. Any ideas ?

Comment: Alright, that doesn't work when $a\equiv 0$, here is my final attempt :

$$\left\lfloor \dfrac{b-a+  a \pmod{n}+ n\delta(a\mod n)}{n}\right\rfloor$$

where $\delta(t) = 1$ when $t=0$, and $0$ otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $d$ to be a divisor of $n$, $d$ must be of the form $2^a \cdot 3^b \cdot 5^c \cdot 7^d \cdot 11^e \cdot 13^f \cdot 37^g$, where $0 \leq a \leq 14, 0 \leq b \leq 9, 0 \leq c \leq 8, 0 \leq d \leq 10, 0 \leq e\leq 3, 0\leq f \leq 5, 0 \leq g \leq 10$.

Now we want $d$ ot be a multiple of the number given, that means $d$ must be of the form $2^a \cdot 3^\color{red}{9} \cdot 5^c \cdot 7^d \cdot 11^e \cdot 13^f \cdot 37^g$, where $\color{red}{10} \leq a \leq 14, \color{red}{2} \leq c \leq 8, \color{red}{5} \leq d \leq 10, \color{red}{2} \leq e\leq 3, \color{red}{2}\leq f \leq 5, \color{red}{2} \leq g \leq 10$.

Now we want $d$ to be a cube as well. This means all powers appearing must by divisible by $3$.  Thus
$$a=12, b=9, c \in \{3,6\}, d \in \{6,9\}, e=3, f=3, g \in \{3,6,9\}.$$
Thus the total number of choices we have  are
$$2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3=12.$$

Comment: how would the answer change if it would have been 3^8 for both numbers instead of 3^9?

Comment: @DevAllanPer If it is $3^8$ for both $n$ and the number whose multiple we are looking for, then such a divisor cannot be a perfect cube.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are required to be a multiple of $2^{10}\cdot3^9\cdot5^2\cdot7^5\cdot11^2\cdot 13^2\cdot37^2$ and **also** a perfect cube, we know that whatever our divisor is, it must be divisible by $2^{12}\cdot3^9\cdot5^3\cdot7^6\cdot11^3\cdot 13^3\cdot37^3$. Now when you run your counting argument, the permissible ranges of exponents should be small enough to match the provided answer.

Comment: You seem to have missed the *that are multiples of* part of the problem statement.  With $k\leq 3$ you are not going to be a multiple of $2^{10}$ nor a multiple of any multiple of $2^{10}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Whoops!